# Site layout only in the browser – really or not?

Tags: firebug, dreamweaver, local

Hello I'm really only just started to create their own websites and there and I need in the layout of the site. Not long thinking I downloaded the notepad++ and began to impose. My friends advised me to get dreamweaver to make it easier but it To facilitate the work, but it seemed slow and difficult. I want make up only a web browser (like in Firebug and Developer Tools Google Chrome) without the other editors but the main difficulty is that they can not edit files directly in local folder on my PC (?) this is implemented in Opera (ctrl+U) but it is not entirely comfortable. There other solutions?
Translation carried out with Google Translate with my edits - do not hurt me much:)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, Dreamweaver is your best bet. I use dreamweaver, I have been for years and I haven't found anything that does the job better. It handles everything perfectly; HTML, javascript, PHP, CSS, everything a budding web designer needs.